# ListView with EditText: create and focus new item on enter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have the following list adapter which is showing a checkbox and an EditText:

```
public class ReminderTaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

private final Activity context;

private final List<Task> tasks;

public ReminderTaskListAdapter(Activity context, List<Task> tasks) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_reminder_task_list_view, tasks);

    this.context = context;
    this.tasks = tasks;
}

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_reminder_task_list_view, null,true);

    Task task = tasks.get(position);

    EditText task_text = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editReminderTaskText);
    task_text.setText(task.getText());

    CheckBox task_is_done_checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editReminderTaskCheckbox);
    //task_is_done_checkbox.setChecked(task.getIs_done());

    task_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //if enter key is pressed...
            if (s.length() > 0 && s.subSequence(s.length()-1, s.length()).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
                Log.d("f", "enter pressed");
                tasks.add(new Task());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });

    return rowView;
};
}
```

As you can see I'm adding a new task when the enter key is pressed.
Now I'd also like to not actually display the new line (i.e. discard the 'enter' keypress) and focus the newly created task. I can't figure out how to access the correct object and which method to call to focus the new EditText.

Issues I'll deal with later:

- creating the new task right below the current and not at the end
- delete the task if it's empty and the 'backspace' key is pressed.
- adding buttons for the same tasks

I'm trying to replicate exactly what Google Keep does.

Comment: using setOnKeyListener may be more convenient here. and by assuming u add new list item to the end you can use if (position == task_size -1) edittext.requestfocus();

Comment: I'm now using setOnKeyListener and I'm able to catch the 'enter' key, and not display it, so it's a success. I can't figure out how to focus the next task. I'm currently in the getView() method of my adapter, so I'm not sure how to get the next EditText instance...

Comment: When u add a new task u should notify list adapter that there is/are change(s) in the list items by calling notifyDataSetChanged(). After that getView method will be called for all the items again. So u can catch the  any view at a position of interest with if condition.

Comment: I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() inside setOnKeyListener, but all the already added tasks disappear.

Comment: make sure u don't recreate tasks object. u can print size in getView to see if it is correctly added

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain correctly. I have one empty task. I write "test", press enter. Now I have two empty tasks ("test" is gone). What is happening?